# How to get the value of an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

In my index.js file I call the function `iterateWagons`

*src/index.js*

```js
import { locomotive } from './data/train.js'
import { iterateWagons, filterOldBreaks } from './utils/train.js'

iterateWagons(
    locomotive,
    wagon => console.log(` ${wagon.name} is a locomotive`),
    wagon => wagon.isLocomotive,
)
```

My goal is to implement this function...

"Walk" through the entire train, when given a starting point (the locomotive). There are three parameters:

- start: the starting point of the train
- actionFn: a function that will be called for each wagon in the train
- filterFn: a function that will be called for each wagon in the train. If it returns false, the wagon will be skipped.

*src/utils/train.js*

```js
export const iterateWagons = (start, actionFn, filterFn) => { ... }
```

When I print out `filterFn` with `console.log(filterFn)` the console prints `[Function (anonymous)]` and I cant get if this is true or false.

**How can I access this?**

---

This is my draft implementation:

*src/utils/train.js*

```js
export const iterateWagons = (start, actionFn, filterFn) => {
    while (start.next) {
        if (filterFn(start)) {
            actionFn(start)
        }
        start = start.next
    }
}
```

with this I get the error `TypeError: filterFn is not a function`

I also tried only using

```js
if (filterFn)
```

but here I didn't get `true` or `false` as expected.

---

Further Information:

- `console.log(filterFn)` -> `[Function (anonymous)]`
- `console.log(filterFn(start))` -> `TypeError: filterFn is not a function`

---

**Project Structure:**

[image: Project Structure]

---

**Data:**

src/data/train.js

```js
[...]

const wagon1 = {
    name: 'W-10582',
    emoji: '',
    lastBreakRevision: '2021-02-15',
    next: wagon2,
}
export const locomotive = {
    name: 'L-283',
    emoji: '',
    isLocomotive: true,
    next: wagon1,
}
```

---

**Solution:**

I got a working solution:

```js
const defaultFilterFn = () => true
const defaultActionFn = wagon => console.log(`${wagon.emoji} ${wagon.name}`)

export const iterateWagons = (start, actionFn, filterFn) => {

    filterFn = filterFn || defaultFilterFn
    actionFn = actionFn || defaultActionFn

    while (start) {
        if (filterFn(start)) {
            actionFn(start)
        } 
        start = start.next
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call the function,  `console.log(filterFn(wagon))`

Comment: @Keith `TypeError: filterFn is not a function`

Comment: I would suggest you show all the code as a snippet, it will help others debug the code.. Inside your question there is a `<>`, this allows you attach your code and make it runnable inside SO.

Comment: Please check the casing on all your variable names. This looks suspiciously like a typo problem.

Comment: I assume you are doing this inside the body of your iterateWagons definition.  Did you try `console.log(filterFn())` ?

Comment: `console.log(filterFn())` -> TypeError: filterFn is not a function @gview

Comment: @Keith due there are a lot of js modules used I think its probably very hard to make it in `<>`

Comment: All we should need is your `iterateWagons` and how your calling it.. We don't need all your js modules.

Comment: @Keith the first code snipped in the question is how I call it and I've updated the question with my implementation of the function (not working for now)

Comment: I believe I understand the root of your problem.  It is that only the first object in your linked list of objects (the locomotive) has an `isLocomotive` property. When the filter runs for wagon1, there is no isLocomotive boolean property. This causes an error in the filterFn.

Answer (score 1):

Small test:

```
func = function(start, fn){fn(start)};
func(2, a=>console.log(`Test ${a}`));
```

This will print `Test 2` on the console. So, your problem might be in the implementation that you did not show.

EDIT:

```
waggon = {"isLocomotive": true};

func = function(start, fn){fn(start)};

func(waggon, a=>console.log(`${a.isLocomotive}`));
```

This prints `true`.

Comment: I've added my implementation at the end of the question

Comment: Your code looks good. But why do you want to call `console.log(filterFn)`? This way you will get information on the object `filterFn`. And when you call `console.log(filterFn(start))` you will get the return value of that call, which is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I think is that you are not understanding scope.  When you pass the parameters, you are invoking the function and it then runs, then completes and is popped off the call stack.

You can indeed console.log() values of a callback function you passed, inside the scope of the outer function.

```js
function t(fooFn) { console.log('Foo is ' + fooFn()) }

t(() => 'value of foo')
```

As you can see, when you pass the arrow function, you can invoke it and get a value from it and console.log it, as I have done in this example.